# Entity Framework Code First navigational properties returning null fields

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

For a program I'm using EF code first for the first time. In the past I used linq to SQL en EF DbFirst. When retreiving the main record'I'm unable to load the subrecords using the navigational properties. I get an empty subrecord with all record-fields are 0 or null.

When I want to apply eager loading. the .Include(x=>x.......) isn't showing my navigationals.

I have set up the following classes:

```
public Record()
    {
        Shipping = new ShippingData();
        Delivery = new DeliveryData();
        Items = new List<Item>();
        ImportDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [Key]
    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public int ShippingId { get; set; }
    public int DeliveryId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ImportDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ShippingData Shipping { get; set; }
    public virtual DeliveryData Delivery { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public virtual Collecting CollectingOrder { get; set; }
```

with the following context:

```
public class TweemansContext : DbContext
{
    public TweemansContext()
        : base("xxxx")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Add.Record> Records { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Add.ShippingData> Shipping { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Add.DeliveryData> Delivery { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Add.Item> ProductItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Add.Kolli> Kolli { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Add.Collecting> CollectingOrders { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Record>().HasRequired(s => s.Shipping)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(s => s.ShippingId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Record>().HasRequired(d => d.Delivery)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.DeliveryId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Record>().HasOptional(c => c.CollectingOrder)
                    .WithOptionalDependent(a => a.Record).Map(p => p.MapKey("CollectionID"));
    }
}
```

the delivery class is a public class as wel as follows:

```
    public class DeliveryData
{
    [Key]
    public int DeliveryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Record Record { get; set; }

    ....lots of public properties
```

now when I try to use lazy loading all my properties of the delivery class are null using the following code:

```
using (TweemansContext context = new TweemansContext())
        {
            var imported = (from record in context.Records
                            where record.ImportDate.Year == date.Year && record.ImportDate.Month == date.Month && record.ImportDate.Day == date.Day
                            select record).ToList();

            foreach (var Record in imported)
            {
                string email;
                string telnr;
                CustomerService service = new CustomerService(connectionString);
                **string servicenr = Record.Delivery.AccountNumber.Substring(2, 8);**
                service.GetUserData(servicenr, out email, out telnr);
                Record.Delivery.Email = email;
                Record.Delivery.TelephoneNbr = telnr;
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

on the rows with the ** my debugger is telling me that delivery exists but all of it's properties are null.

When wanting to apply an include as follows the .include isn't showing my navigation:

```
    var imported = (from record in context.Records.Include(x=>x.)
                            where 
                               record.ImportDate.Year == date.Year 
                               && record.ImportDate.Month == date.Month
                               && record.ImportDate.Day == date.Day
                            select record).ToList();
```

What am I doing wrong, or which part have i misuderstood??

Comment: in your Context constructor add these lines: `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;`

Comment: Tried it but without any succes to my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must remove the initialization of the navigation *references* from the `Record` constructor, the initialization of the empty navigation *collection* is OK:

```
Shipping = new ShippingData(); // remove this line
Delivery = new DeliveryData(); // remove this line
```

Essentially these lines "overwrite" the loaded data with values that the constructors of `ShippingData` and `DeliveryData` set, probably the default values `0` and `null`.

Side note about your remark "*the .Include(x=>x.......) isn't showing my navigationals*". You need to put `using System.Data.Entity;` at the beginning of your code file to make the `Include` extension method available that takes a lambda expression as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When your debug stop there you should be getting a proxy class on Delivery. if you are no getting this you should enable lazy load on your context. You can check [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnforum/archive/2010/07/12/community-goodies-lazy-loading-in-entity-framework-4.aspx) how to enable lazy load.

If you don't want to enable lazy load you should use Include in your query to include the Delivery information. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) you can have some info how to use include.

Comment: I want lazy loading, but lazy loading should be enable by default when using codefirst. Lazy loading seems to work because I get an instance off delivery, only no fields are loaded from the database.