# Entity Framework 6.1 - code first - reference properties not loading correctly

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I've noticed an issue with EF 6.1 code first. I have the following classes -

```
namespace Domain
{
    public interface ISupportsOptimisticConcurrency
    {
        byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    }

    public class Entity : ISupportsOptimisticConcurrency
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    }

    public class Lookup : Entity
    {
        public Lookup()
        {
            Description = string.Empty;
        }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(300)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class GroupType : Lookup
    {
    }

    public class Group:Entity
    {
        public Group()
        {
                GroupType = new GroupType();
        }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid ExternalId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string MonitorEmail { get; set; }

        public string UrlRequestEmail { get; set; }

        public bool UsesDefaultOptions { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("GroupType")]
        public int GroupTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual GroupType GroupType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've written a typical Repository class for accessing data from DB. Now, when I try to find a Group by Id, and include the GroupType, the GroupType doesn't load properly, and the Name property of GroupType comes as null.

Interestingly, when I removed the Group constructor which initializes a new GroupType, things start working fine.

Could you please explain this behavior?
Note: This same scenario works fine with NHibernate as it is.

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: If i had to guess, i would say has something to do with the inheritance (and multiple non-abstract types). There's no additional properties available for GroupType so the discriminator probably gets confused. `Entity` should probably be `abstract` for starters, then work on either defining or declaring a discriminator for `Lookup` vs `GroupType`.

Comment: Likely what is happening is EF sees there is already a GroupType so it doesn't instantiate a new one. Why do you have the constructor instantiating GroupType? Are you conflating it with collection navigation properties? Those get instantiated in the constructor, but singular reference navigation properties aren't supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to remove the initialization logic in the Group constructor:

```
 GroupType = new GroupType();
```

This probably overwrites the loaded data or does not even load it (because it already was instantiated), causing the GroupType property to be the instance that you initialized it with instead of the one in the database.

It may be the same issue as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590905/entity-framework-code-first-navigational-properties-returning-null-fields).

Comment: Yes, I'll have to do just that, but it goes against the principles of OO, because if I don't initialize a reference type in the constructor, I cannot use C# object initialization syntax e.g. this fails -

    var gr = new Group()
            {
                Name = "name",
                GroupType =
                    {
                        Name = "gt",
                        Description = "desc"
                    }
            };

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to do this. Initializing a collection is something you might want to do, but initializing a reference type would be something that you don't do in a constructor. Being null is a valid state for a property.